# M87 Black Hole's Radius

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, singularities

I'm curious about the actual radius of M87 black hole. I know they've recently found out its Schwarzschild radius is around $2\times10^{13} $m, with a mass of $6.5$ billion solar masses. But I wonder if we know the actual radius of the black hole? As in how much smaller is the black hole compared to the sun (by radius)?

Answer (score 2):

The Schwarzschild radius is about the closest thing you can come to "the radius" of a black hole. We cannot see anything from inside there, so we have no idea how much smaller the actual "object" involved must be, or even whether there is even an object at all, and the self-similarity of black hole geometries means that it provides a useful yardstick for discussing phenomena related thereto. And it has a clean referent: generally speaking, anything that gets closer than this cannot escape (in an ideal black hole in pure general relativity, this is exactly true).

Moreover, the alterations to geometry mean that strictly speaking there isn't really a clear "radius" that is directly comparable to things in our relatively Euclidean familiar space. Thus this is about the best we'll get.

If you want a comparison to the Solar System, this radius, more neatly expressed as 20 000 Gm, means that if placed at the center thereof in place of the Sun, it would extend to about 3x the orbit of Pluto, 6500 Gm, but only 1/5 the way to the inner Oort cloud, 100 000 Gm (the outer is somewhere around or past $10^{7}$ Gm). This makes the black hole much *larger* than the Sun, whose radius is only around 0.6 Gm.